# order matters with return-from in SBCL

Tags: return, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm on Day 3 of trying to learn Common Lisp (SBCL) by doing [Advent of Code](http://adventofcode.com/2018/). I understand there is more than one type of `return`. I'm wondering if someone could explain to me why the following function will return `nil` (this makes sense)

```
(defun fn (n)
    (cond ((zerop n) 
           (return-from fn nil))
          (t  
           (write-line "Hello World") 
           (fn (- n 1)))))
```

but the following function will return "Hello World" (this does not make sense to me).

```
(defun fn (n)
    (cond ((zerop n) 
           (return-from fn nil))
          (t 
           (fn (- n 1)) 
           (write-line "Hello World"))))
```

I found a great post covering some aspects of SBCL's `return` behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38387789/1456421), but to my understanding it doesn't seem to address this particular detail.

EDIT: a `loop` call is a more sensible way of writing this function, but it is not the way that I discovered this behaviour. My suspicion is that this behaviour arises because `fn` is called recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I started writing this before Sylwester's answer, which is mostly better I think.)

A critical difference between Lisp-family languages and many other languages is that Lisp-family languages are 'expression languages'.  What this means technically is that  languages like (say) C or Python there are two sorts of constructs:

- expressions, which have values;
- statements, which do not;

While in Lisp-family languages there is one sort of thing: expressions, which have values.  Lisp-family languages are sometimes called 'expression languages' as a result of this.

This makes a huge difference if you want to write functions, which are things which return values (a function call is an expression in other words).

### Conventional languages (Python as an example)

In a language which is not an expression language then if you're defining a function and find yourself in the middle of some construct which is a statement and you want to return a value, you have to use some special magic construct, often called `return` to do that.  So in Python, where conditionals are statements, you might write:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

And in fact you *have* to use `return` because the body of a function definition in Python is a series of statements, so to return any kind of value at all you need to use `return`.

In fact, Python (and C, and Java &c &c) have a special form of a conditional which is an expression: in Python this looks like this:

```
def fib(n):
    return n if n < 2 else (fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

It looks different in C but it does the same thing.

But you still need this annoying `return` (OK, only one of them now) & that brings to light another feature of such languages: if some place in the syntax wants a statement you generally need to have a statement there, or if you can put an expression there its value just gets dropped.  So you can try something like this:

```
def fib(n):
    n if n < 2 else (fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

And that's syntactically OK -- the expression gets turned into a statement -- but it fails at runtime because the function no longer returns a useful value.  In Python you can get around this if you want people to hate you:

```
fib = lambda n: n if n < 2 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Python people will hate you if you do this, and it's also not useful, because Python's `lambda` *only* takes expressions so what you can write is crippled.

### Lisp

Lisp has none of this: in Lisp *everything is an expression* and therefore *everything has a value*, you just need to know where it comes from.  There is still `return` (in CL, anyway) but you need to use it much less often.

But, of course people often do want to write programs which look like 'do this, then do this, then do this', where most of the doing is being done for side-effect, so Lisps generally have some kind of sequencing construct, which lets you just have a bunch of expressions one after the other, all but (typically) one of which get evaluated for side-effect.  In CL the most common sequencing construct is called `progn` (for historical reasons).  `(progn ...)` is an expression made of other expressions, and its value is the value of last expression in its body.

`progn` is so useful in fact that a bunch of other constructs have 'implicit `progn`s' in them.  Two examples are function definitions (the body of `defun` is an implicit `progn`) and `cond` (the body of a `cond`-clause is an implicit `progn).

### Your function

Here is your function (first version) with its various parts notated

```
(defun fn (n)
  ;; the body of fn is an implicit progn with one expression, so
  ;; do this and return its value
  (cond
   ;; the value of cond is the value of the selected clause, or nil
   ((zerop n)
    ;; the body of this cond clause is an implicit progn with on
    ;; expression so do this and ... it never returns
    (return-from fn nil))
   (t
    ;; the body of this cond clause is an implicit progn with two expressions, so
    ;; do this for side-effect
    (write-line "Hello World")
    ;; then do this and return its value
    (fn (- n 1)))))
```

Here is the second version

```
(defun fn (n)
  ;; the body of fn is an implicit progn with one expression, so
  ;; do this and return its value
  (cond
   ;; the value of cond is the value of the selected clause, or nil
   ((zerop n)
    ;; the body of this cond clause is an implicit progn with on
    ;; expression so do this and ... it never returns
    (return-from fn nil))
   (t
    ;; the body of this cond clause is an implicit progn with two expressions, so
    ;; do this for side-effect
    (fn (- n 1))
    ;; then do this and return its value
    (write-line "Hello World"))))
```

So you can see what is happening here: in the first version the value that gets returned is either `nil` or the value of the recursive call (also `nil`).  In the second version the value that gets returned is either `nil` or whatever `write-line` returns.  And it turns out that `write-line` returns the value of its argument, so that's what you get if you call it with an integer greater than zero.

### Why have `return-from` at all in Lisp?

One thing that should be immediately clear from this whole expression-language thing is that you hardly ever need to explicitly return something in Lisp: you just have an expression that computes the value you want.  But there are two good uses (which perhaps are really the same use) of explicit returns.

The first is that sometimes you are doing some big search for something in the form of a bunch of nested loops and at some point you just want to say 'OK, found it, here's the answer'.  You can do that in one of two ways: you can carefully structure your loops so that once you find what you're after they all terminate nicely and the value gets passed back up, or you can just say 'here's the answer'.  The latter thing is what `return-from` does: it just says 'I'm done now, unwind the stack carefully and return this':

```
(defun big-complicated-search (l m n)
  (dotimes (i l)
    (dotimes (j m)
      (dotimes (k n)
        (let ((it (something-involving i j k l m n)))
          (when (interesting-p it)
            (return-from big-complicated-search it)))))))
```

And `return-from` does this *in the right way*:

```
(defun big-complicated-file-search (file1 file2)
  (with-open-file (f1 file1)
    (with-open-file (f2 file2)
      ...
      (when ...
        (return-from big-complicated-search found)))))
```

When you call this, and when the thing is found, `return-from` will make sure that the two files you have opened are properly closed.

The second, which is really almost the same thing, is that sometimes you need to just give up, and `return-from` is a good way of doing this: it returns immediately, deals with clean-ups (see above) and is generally a nice way of saying 'OK, I give up now'.  At first blush this seems like something you would do with some kind of exception-handling system, but in fact there are two critical differences:

- in an exception-handling system (which CL has, of course), you need some kind of exception to raise so you might need to invent something;
- exception-handling systems are *dynamic* not *lexical*: if you raise an exception then the thing that gets to handle it is hunted for up the stack dynamically: this means that you're at the mercy of anyone who stuck a handler in the way and it also typically rather slow.

Finally the exceptional-return-via-error-handling-mechanism is just, well, horrid.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike C language family Lisp has the feature that everything is expressions. That means you "return" the result of an expression. eg.

```
(+ (if (< x 0) 
       (- x) 
       x) 
    3)
```

Here the result of the `if` is that it will be the absolute value of `x`. Thus if `x` is `-5` or `5` the result of the expression is `8`. You can write `abs` like this:

```
(defun my-abs (v)
  (if (< v 0)
      (- v)
      v))
```

Notice I do not use `return`. THe result of the `if` is the last expression and that means the result of that is the result of `my-abs`.

Your two functions can  be written like this:

```
(defun fn1 (n)
  (cond 
    ((zerop n) nil)
    (t (write-line "Hello World") (fn1 (- n 1)))))
```

And

```
(defun fn2 (n)
  (cond 
    ((zerop n) nil)
    (t (fn2 (- n 1)) (write-line "Hello World"))))
```

Needless to say `(write-line "Hello World")` returns its argument in addition to print the argument. Thus whenever it is the last expression it will be the result. 
For every `n` above 0 it will do the recursions first and each end every one except the first will return `"Hello World"`. If you call `(fn2 0)` the result is `nil`, the same as `fn1`.

**EDIT**

One might ask what is the purpose of `return` and `return-from` when there obviously is little use for it. If you want something else than the default result in a `loop` macro the common way to do it by `finally` clause.

```
(defun split-by (test list &key (return-form #'values))
  "Split a list in two groups based on test"
  (loop :for e :in list
        :if (funcall test e) 
          :collect e :into alist
        :else 
          :collect e :into blist
        :finally (return (funcall return-form alist blist))))

(split-by #'oddp '(1 2 3 4) :return-form #'list)
; ==> ((1 3) (2 4))
```

Another way is if you are doing recursion and want to cancel everything when you know the result you can use `return-from`:

```
(defun find-tree-p (needle haystack &key (test #'eql))
  "search the tree for element using :test as comparison"      
  (labels ((helper (tree)
             (cond ((funcall test tree needle) 
                    (return-from find-tree t))
                   ((consp tree) 
                    (helper (car tree)) 
                    (helper (cdr tree)))
                   (t nil))))
   (helper haystack)))


(find-tree '(f g) '(a b c (d e (f g) q) 1 2 3) :test #'equal)
; ==> (f g) ; t
```

Now if you hadn't done `return-from` you would have had logic to check the returned value to see if you needed to continue or not. If you want to process elements and don't want to pass twice to check validity before computing the result, you can just start computing and use `return-from` as a `call/cc`. This function can be used to map over lists of lists and it stops at the shortest list so needs to become `()` when the first sublist is empty:

```
(defun cdrs (lists)
  "return the cdrs if all elements are cons, () otherwise"      
  (loop :for list :in lists
        :when (null list) :do (return-from cdrs '())
        :collect (cdr list)))

(cdrs '((a) (b) (c))) ; ==> (nil nil nil)
(cdrs '((a) (b) ()))  ; ==> ()
```

Comment: When is it necessary to use `return` or `return-from`? If every expression returns a value, this makes it seem to me as though `return` is typically unnecessary (but perhaps maybe for breaking out of a loop or something?)

Comment: @bashfuloctopus Not often, but I've added som examples.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
(defun fn (n)
  (cond ((zerop n) (return-from fn nil))
    (t (write-line "Hello World") (fn (- n 1)))
    )
  )
```

There is a bunch of things slightly wrong with above code:

```
(defun fn (n)
  (cond ((zerop n) (return-from fn nil))         ; 1) the return from is not needed
    (t (write-line "Hello World") (fn (- n 1)))  ; 2) this line is not correctly
                                                 ;    indented
    )                                            ; 3) dangling parentheses Don't. Never.
                                                 ;    also: incorrect indentation 
  )
```

1. the first `cond` clause already returns a value, just write `nil` as the return value. Then the whole `cond` returns this value. It is very rare that you need `return` or `return-from` from a `cond` clause.
2. use an editor to indent your code. In GNU Emacs / SLIME the command <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> will indent the expression. For help about the editor commands in the current mode see: <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> for *mode help*.
3. indent correctly and don't use dangling parentheses. They are useless in Lisp. Learn to use the editor to correctly indent code - that's much more useful than to place wrongly indented parentheses on their own line. <kbd>tab</kbd> indents the current line.

It's more useful to format the code like this for a beginner:

```
(defun fn (n)
  (cond ((zerop n)
         (return-from fn nil))
        (t
         (write-line "Hello World")
         (fn (- n 1)))))
```

Code then will look more like a prefix tree.

Also don't forget to disable inserting tabs in GNU Emacs Put this into your emacs init file: `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`. You can evaluate Emacs Lisp expressions also on the fly with <kbd>meta></kbd>-<kbd>:</kbd>.

Now according to 1. above code is usually written as:

```
(defun fn (n)
  (cond ((zerop n)
         nil)
        (t
         (write-line "Hello World")
         (fn (- n 1)))))
```

When `n` is zero, the first clause is selected and its last value is returned. The other clauses are not looked at -> `cond` returns `nil` -> the function `fn` returns `nil`.

Usually I would write above recursive function like this:

```
(defun fn (n)
  (unless (zerop n)
    (write-line "Hello World")
    (fn (- n 1))))
```

`unless` returns `nil` if `(zerop n)` is true. Another variant:

```
(defun fn (n)
  (when (plusp n)
    (write-line "Hello World")
    (fn (- n 1))))
```

**You CAN use `return-from`, but in case it was not clear: you don't need it most of the time.**

Comment: actually, my (entirely default) slime set-up is causing this bizarre indentation behaviour.

Comment: @bashfuloctopus: that's why I mentioned to get rid of the tabs and SLIME will do the right thing. It makes it easier to post code here...

Comment: Unfortunately `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` has no effect. There must be some other default floating around that's responsible for correct indentation behaviour, or this option is clashing with some other option somewhere.

Comment: @bashfuloctopus put it into `~/.emacs` and restart emacs. Then start slime, edit a new file and indent code. There should be no tabs.  If your old file already has tabs untabify it: select the whole buffer and call m-x untabify   -> then you can save the file etc.

Comment: I am still not sure what effect this should have, as it still seems to have no effect on my machine. The code indents just as before, and still leaves parentheses at weird and aesthetically unpleasing indentation levels.

Comment: @bashfuloctopus: probably good to ask about setting up emacs for Lisp in /r/lisp on reddit or similar.